# How to use if else logic in selenium ide chrome extension

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

Here is my task scenario… if id appears on the page then click

Else click other options

When I run the program it does work for the if condition as it appears on the page and its click the button but when I run the program for the other user and it doesn’t appear on the page it should click on the else condition but it's still looking for the if condition and gets failed.

How I can overcome this issue. Any idea, please. Thank you

I have tried selenium API control flow example as well as different forum example but did not work so far.

```
 Command          Target                        Value

 store                                           id
 if               ${id} = 'spellcheck-save'
    click          id=spellcheck-save
 else
    click         css=.md-button > .fa-save
 end
```

HTML Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please also provide a minimal HTML page example for which this logic fails.

Comment: @InonPeled I have added  HTML page. for some user when they log in it appears a spellcheck window where a user can save or cancel. But for some user, this option doesn't appear so they can go to else option.